# Can we transfer a vue.js project to a nuxt.js project and how?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Hi everyone clearly can we transfer a vuejs application to nuxt.js without worry or by copying and pasting the views and component images without destroying all ??
and nuxt.js he solves the problem of SEO and google bots knowing that for the moment j no backend and that the data in front is fixed ??
this question is for people experimenting with nuxt.js and vue.js Thanks to you

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very relative.

I'll try some tips for you, and maybe you can look at the options.

Nuxt is a framework, it works in a pre-defined way, you need to create the structure of your code inside an appropriate folders. Example are the stores, layouts, the pages or the components...

So, let's assume that you have a vue component and need to migrate it to NuxtJs. The code inside the component is a little different, but not so much, because in the vue you need to declare the vue instance, and import the things to render, since Nuxt does this in an automated way, you will not create new vue instances, only a .vue file and configure the  and  sessions. Nuxt will generate things for you automatically. So the programming is more dynamic.

Therefore, you will not need to recreate all of your code, but you will need to re-tag it in the Nuxt pattern. Which in fact is unfortunately almost the same thing as recreating everything again.

But think on the bright side, you will be using your entire code blocks, which will make development very fast.

So what you will have to do is to recreate the entire structure of pages, components, layouts, copying their excerpts from the vue application codes to the new files within the Nuxt directory structure. It will be a lot of work, but I'm sure the end result will be much better.

It makes no sense for your application to not use nuxt, for hundreds of thousands of reasons.

That's it, I hope I helped you.

Comment: I do not understand all of this promotion on vue.js if nuxt.js is sufficient on its own. do you need 2 projects, one vue.js and one nuxt to run a project, I don't really understand the principle of keeping vue.js from the moment that nuxt.js and a full-fledged application that solves Vue problems. js ??

Comment: and I don't understand why release new vue.js 3 if we don't launch a vue.js project. But do we have to launch a nuxt.js project to solve Vue.js problems? What's the point ? thank you

Comment: I believe that in fact everything depends on the level of complexity of the project. For a simple application, you don't need a sophistication as complete as Nuxts, however, the moment the application grows, nuxt is perfect and makes everything very simple and scalable.

Comment: vue is a javascript programming framework, already nuxt is a concept of applicability of this framework in my understanding, of course. Nuxt makes the vue even more powerful.

Comment: I think Nuxt is that structured project model that everyone should follow. But when you create your own structural organization, it is much more complex than simply following the method proposed in Nuxt.

At first I made a system in Vue, but when I realized that what I needed was Nuxt's structure and scalability, it was necessary to start again. Sad but today I don't regret it.

Comment: yes but to have a vue.js project on the internet is to have a phantom project for SEO robots so ultimately it is of no use to use these frameworks without nuxt.js because the goal of a site is anyway its referencing if not the techno inside is not used much since the site must still be found on the internet and it is a huge defect what do you think?

Comment: yes and no, because there are ways to achieve the same result using a set of packages, or developing your own libraries, but it will certainly be much more work than simply getting what is ready. For example, when implementing vue-meta in a project without nuxt, you will have the same skills as this feature, only in a context that follows your pattern. But if we are going to follow the line of a project with a project structure based on webpackage, the root of our project is almost identical to Nuxt.

Comment: It is almost an inevitable path to follow for Nuxt, because the resources he adds in a very simple way in his project are indisputable. 
but I agree with you that when we found this out, we already spent a lot of time creating our own ecosystem. Which creates a certain discomfort. But when this model is adopted, we stop headbanging and everything is much simpler. As I said earlier, you only win. Build an incredible platform on top of Nuxt, it's incredibly fast, efficient, intelligent, it's a pleasure to create a system in this format.